# Setup Airtel PRi Using DGm Card in Ubuntu OS

Tags: server, asterisk

I am trying to install DHM card in Ubuntu OS.

I have taken AIRTEL PRI in India.

I'm confused with number of digits of number we need to send while making outbound calls.

While using reliance in India, we can send 6 digit numbers(DAHDI).

Does anyone know about AIRTEL PRI configuration parameters?

Comment: Can you please provide more information.  What version of Ubuntu you're using; what hardware you are trying to configure, and what interfaces you're using.  Screenshots and error messages would be ideal. :)

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my server.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error from AIRTEL team, they were passing wrong parameter over their network - now it got resolved my network team of Airtel - thanks for your time.

The problem was related to network parameters. 
We passed 10 digit telephone number and it worked.
Asterisk was configured locally by Airtel team. 
Its better to talk to local network provider to resolve such issues because they have complete idea of what param need to pass locally server.